# R why the second random number generating function takes much longer

Tags: r

Please check the following code and see how the second `runif` take much more time.

```
library(profvis)

profvis({
  runif(100000,0,1)
  runif(100000,0,1)
})
```

Comment: This isn't a meaningful difference, it's just because the function is too fast to profile effectively. Try running it a few more times.